# How to convert a string to PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI.Text object?

Tags: pysimplegui

I want to change my layout in pysimplegui based on the contents of a dictionary.
I have a pysimplegui layout which shows a list of data similar to below;

```
thing1   value1   (inputbox1)
thing2   value2   (inputbox2)
thing3   value3   (inputbox3)
```

where the inputbox# is where the user should input data, but 'thing#' and 'value#' are normal text.

I am trying to take the values of these from a dictionary, and do it while iterating because the amount of values in the dictionary will change.  This means the amount of rows will change depending on how many values are in the dictionary.

I thought to convert string data and append to 'col'.  I checked the datatype inside 'col' in order to figure out what I had to convert the string data to.

`col=[     [sg.Text('john')],     sg.Text('john'), ]`

where the layout has;
`[sg.Column(col,size=(1420,600),scrollable=True)],`

I asked to print up the value, and the data type for each and found;

col[0] is [<PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI.Text object at 00x00000298BA1A67A0>] <class 'list'>
col[1] is <PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI.Text object at 0x00000298BA1A5E70> <class 'PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI.Text'>

I am trying to take the values of these from a dictionary, and do it while iterating because the amount of values in the dictionary will change.  This means the amount of rows will change depending on how many values are in the dictionary.
I'm trying to convert string data to <PySimpleGUI.PySimpleGUI.Text object.  Is this possible?  Is there a better/easier/accepted way?

Update.
I ended up using a comprehensive loop, which I hadn't seen before.  The line is inside a layout and is similar to

```
[[sg.Text(dict[globproj][f'Cost{i}'])] for i in range(1,amt_cost)],
```

Where amt_cost is the number of items, and Cost{i} is their price.  This worked.  Outside of a column.
I think it worked because the layout is essentially a list, and you can't have a loop in a list, but this comprehensive loop is part of the item, and can therefore be in the list.
I think anyway, I'm not sure.  But it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, PySimpleGUI don't support dynamic layout, but an special method `window.extend_layout` to add new layout. You need to manage the dynamic layout by yourself to decide which row to hide and how many rows to add.

```py
import PySimpleGUI as sg

def new_json(jsonOK):
    global total
    column = window['COLUMN']
    size = len(jsonOK)
    for i in range(total):
        window[f'Item {i}'].update(visible=True)
    if size > total:
        for i in range(total, size):
            item_layout = [[sg.Text("Name", size=0, pad=(5, 0), key=f"Name {i}"), sg.Push(), sg.Input("VALUEE", size=20, pad=(5, 0), key=f"VALUEE {i}")]]
            column_layout = [[sg.pin(sg.Column(item_layout, expand_x=True, pad=(3, 1), key=f'Item {i}'), expand_x=True)]]
            window.extend_layout(column, column_layout)
        total = size
    elif size < total:
        for i in range(size, total):
            window[f'Item {i}'].update(visible=False)
    for i, item in enumerate(jsonOK):
        window[f'Name {i}'].update(item["Name"])
        window[f'VALUEE {i}'].update(item["VALUEE"])
    window.refresh()
    column.contents_changed()
    window.refresh()
    window.move_to_center()

jsonOK = [
    {"Name":"hello","VALUEE":0.9,"OK":"OK","YES":"True","DDD":"EEE","100":100,"100":500},
    {"Name":"apple","VALUEE":0.8,"OK":"NG","YES":"True","DDD":"AAA","100":400,"100":100},
    {"Name":"aaaaa","VALUEE":0.7,"OK":"OK","YES":"True","DDD":"CCC","100":100,"100":300},
    {"Name":"ccccc","VALUEE":0.3,"OK":"NG","YES":"True","DDD":"ZZZ","100":200,"100":100},
]

jsonOK222 = [
    {"Name":"1111", "VALUEE":0.9,"OK":"OK","YES":"True","DDD":"EEE","100":100,"100":500},
    {"Name":"2222", "VALUEE":0.8,"OK":"NG","YES":"True","DDD":"AAA","100":400,"100":100},
    {"Name":"3333", "VALUEE":0.7,"OK":"OK","YES":"True","DDD":"CCC","100":100,"100":300},
    {"Name":"4444", "VALUEE":0.3,"OK":"NG","YES":"True","DDD":"ZZZ","100":200,"100":100},
    {"Name":"aaaaa","VALUEE":0.7,"OK":"OK","YES":"True","DDD":"CCC","100":100,"100":300},
    {"Name":"ccccc","VALUEE":0.3,"OK":"NG","YES":"True","DDD":"ZZZ","100":200,"100":100},
]
string = "1234567890abcdefghij"
jsonOK999 = [{"Name":string[i]*5, "VALUEE":f'{i/10:.1f}',"OK":"OK","YES":"True","DDD":"EEE","100":100,"100":500} for i in range(20)]
total = 20

sg.set_options(font=('Courier New', 11))

column_layout = []
for i in range(total):
    item_layout = [[sg.Text("Name", size=0, pad=(5, 0), key=f"Name {i}"), sg.Push(), sg.Input("VALUEE", size=20, pad=(5, 0), key=f"VALUEE {i}")]]
    column_layout.append([sg.pin(sg.Column(item_layout, expand_x=True, pad=(3, 1), key=f'Item {i}'), expand_x=True)])

layout =  [
    [sg.Button('jsonOK'), sg.Button('jsonOK222'), sg.Button('jsonOK999')],
    [sg.Column(column_layout, expand_x=True, expand_y=True, scrollable=True,  vertical_scroll_only=True, key='COLUMN')],
]
location = sg.Window.get_screen_size()
window = sg.Window('Example', layout, element_justification='center', margins=(0, 3), location=location, finalize=True)

events = {'jsonOK':jsonOK, 'jsonOK222':jsonOK222, 'jsonOK999':jsonOK999}
new_json(jsonOK)

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WINDOW_CLOSED:
        break
    elif event in events:
        new_json(events[event])

window.close()
```

[image]